# How to pass a pointer to the "DEFINED" constant to a function in C?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, queue

I have this enqueue function that takes in a queue pointer and an int pointer to enqueue. I have this constant defined as

```
#DEFINE ENGINE 1
```

and I want to pass it to the function. However, I get an error saying this is an integer and can't be cast to int*. Then I tried to pass it by putting a "&" but it did not work either as I need a real variable instead of a defined constant. Also (int *) did not work either. Is there an easy way to cast my variable so that the function accepts it?

```
int queueEnqueue(queue* q, int* value){
         if(!queueIsFull(q)){
                  q->rear = (q->rear + 1) % q->capacity;
                  q->array[q->rear] = *value;
                  q->size = q->size + 1;
                  return(1);
          }

          return(0);
  }
```

```
queueEnqueue(queue, ENGINE);
```

Comment: Why'd you need the second argument to be a pointer?

Comment: That said, you can take address of a variable, not a value.

Comment: When I change the second argument to the integer it works. I just wanted to learn how to work with pointers and casting but I guess this was not very related. Thank you.

Comment: DEFINED is value but not variable so you can't pass it's address into function. You can initialize some variable with this value and pass address of that variable into function. but it does not make sense to pass pass variable by reference unless your variable is big (has the size which is bigger than pointer) or you want to modify it inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, better to pass the second integer argument as integer like:

```
int queueEnqueue(queue* q, int value)
```

And call it as:

```
queueEnqueue(queue, ENGINE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no reason to use a pointer here. Pointers and references are used when you don't want to pay for copying data or you want to modify their content such that the caller also sees the changes.

The reason it doesn't work in your case is the address of a number is meaningless. You can only take the address of variables.

If you want to use a reference here you can use a const & it will prolong the lifetime of temporary:

```
int queueEnqueue(queue* q, const int& value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro `ENGINE` has no type, you have to cast directly when the function called.

```
queueEnqueue(queue, (int *)(ENGINE));
```

Anyway it makes no sense to use pointer in that case and you will get segmentation fault if it is not a code of an embedded system. If you write your code to an embedded system and `ENGINE` contains a real physical address it must be aligned to 4 bytes when you access with an integer pointer otherwise it lead to exception/trap.